# atom was not found in list of supported editors error when creating new package using mm and atom

Tags: mavensmate

I used to use sublime and was thinking of give atom a try. Installed mavensmate-app and atom package for mavensmate and create new project. Then I got this error:

[image: mm error]

I have configured the global setting of mm_atom_exec_path as follows:

[image: mm configure]

I have copied the whole atom folder into program files (x86) and the location proves to be working in cmd. I have also tried using the default installation location of atom.exe which is under AppData and it is not working as well.

It does create a folder and the content in my workspace. But I am still getting the error which means the project is not created in Atom for MM.

As this is windows I understand there might be case-sensitive issue. So I tried with a little different case but definitely all of them. Is there any other settings I should configure? I can't find anything now.